# what do these "let" and "get' mean?

Tags: vbscript, activex

here is some documentation generated from activeX, can you explain me what do those "let" and "get" mean?

```
Public Property Get ReadyState() ' property ReadyState
Public Property Get TotalFrames() ' property TotalFrames
Public Property Get Playing() ' property Playing
Public Propety Let Playing() ' property Playing
Public Property Get Quality() ' property Quality
Public Propety Let Quality() ' property Quality
Public Property Get ScaleMode() ' property ScaleMode
Public Propety Let ScaleMode() ' property ScaleMode
Public Property Get AlignMode() ' property AlignMode
Public Propety Let AlignMode() ' property AlignMode
```

I am a Java developer, I need to embed a activex control in my java gui application

Comment: if these just like "getters" and "setters" in java, then what are actual type of these properties?

Comment: This is Visual Basic syntax, ignoring the missing `r` for a moment.  VB (and COM) distinguishes between Let and Set.  Set is for object references.  Not very useful in Java of course, especially since it doesn't support properties.  Not quite sure but I think it depends on methods that are prefixed with get_ and set_ to mimic property getters and setters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed, these correspond to "getters" and "setters".  However, the syntax looks wrong.  I suppose that the type *could* be Variant (which would probably not have a corresponding type for Java), but in that case, I would expect the Property Let code to be:

```
Public Property Let MyValue(ByVal value)
End Property
```

Normally, you should include the type:

```
Public Property Let MyValue(ByVal value As Integer)
End Property

Public Property Get MyValue As Integer
End Property
```

I would go back to the tool which gave you this nonsense VB and see if you get better information.  Alternatively, you need something which will allow you to read the type library of the OCX control.  If you don't have Visual Basic, you will be able to use VBA in Word, Excel, Access etc.

Comment: I used a tool called ActivXplorer

Comment: Do you mean I can use VBA to see API information of a OCX control?